# How to hit a Breakpoint in a Command-Line-Tool which is called by another Tool?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging, command-line

I got a Solution with a WPF-Project and a Command-Line-Project. The WPF-Tool is calling the Command-Line-Tool using a `Process` transferring Information as Command-Line-Arguments.

How do I debug the Command-Line-Tool? When I set a breakpoint in my Command-Line-Tool and start the WPF-Tool to Debug it the Breakpoint within the CommandLine-Tool says `the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document`

Answer (score 1):

Attach your debugger to your command-line-tool. Start your command-line-tool, put your breakpoint in and attach visual studio to your command-line-tool.

[image]

And then in the list select your command-line-tool.

Comment: This is not working because the Command-Line Tool is not running. It is called from the WPF-Tool, writes something to the Console-Output-Stream and quits. So I have no chance to attach to it.

Comment: Can't you put a pause in your console?

Comment: Putting a pause in your program is actually a great idea. while you call your executable from the command prompt, the new process hangs in the air so you can locate and attach your debugger to it, and then hit something to continue your execution